# How to use interface methods in main file in go?

Tags: go

I have an interface in the service package

**databaseService.go**

```
package service

    import "gitlab.com/xert/customerservice/internal/database/models"
    
    type CustomerdetailsServiceInterface interface {
        // Remove deletes a user by user name from database.
    
        
        Add()
    }
```

Then I have another service file  customerDetailsService.go,where i am implementing the interface methods

```
type CustomerdetailService struct {
}

func Add(ud *CustomerdetailService) {
    fmt.Println("hello")

}
```

Now when I am trying to use it my main.go

```
import (
    
    "gitlab.com/xert/customerservice/internal/database/service"
)

    func main() {
    
        
    
        service.CustomerdetailsServiceInterface.Add() // this is complaining too few arguments
    
    }
```

How to call the method like this, implement methods in other file?

Comment: the struct `CustomerdetailService` does not implement the interface — at least not in the code you showed. Moreover with the syntax `service.CustomerdetailsServiceInterface` you are calling the method on the interface type. You have to call it on an actual instance instead

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented `CustomerdetailsServiceInterface` in the first place. Following is the way you can implement it.

```
type CustomerdetailService struct {}

func (ud *CustomerdetailService) Add() {
    fmt.Println("hello")

}
```

See the following code, hope it will help you understanding interface in go.

```
package main
import ( 
    "fmt"
)

type CustomerdetailsServiceInterface interface {
    Add()
}

type CustomerdetailService struct{}

func (ud *CustomerdetailService) Add() {
    fmt.Println("hello")

}

type AnotherCustomerdetailService struct{}

func (ud *AnotherCustomerdetailService) Add() {
    fmt.Println("Modified Addition")

}

func main() {
    var x CustomerdetailsServiceInterface

    x = &CustomerdetailService{}
    x.Add()

    x = &AnotherCustomerdetailService{}
    x.Add()
}
```

You can not call a method directly on interface but you will need a variable with a type which implements the interface. In the above case it's `CustomerdetailService` which implements `CustomerdetailsServiceInterface`.